# How to determine the Page Frame Number for device memory?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

How does one determine the page frame number for device memory? From LDD3/ Ch. 15/ sections "Using remap_pfn_range" and "A Simple Implementation", pfn has been equated to the vm_pgoff field. I am confused by this. How can that be so?

Note that vm_pgoff is described as:

> The offset of the area in the file, in pages. When a file or device is
>   mapped, this is the file position of the first page mapped in this
>   area.

Thus if the first page mapped corresponds to the first page of the file as well (which, I think would be quite common), vm_pgoff would be 0. correct? If so, this doesn't seem to be the correct value for the pfn parameter of remap_pfn_range( ).  What am I missing here? What is the correct value? For ease of reference, I am reproducing the relevant code from LDD3 below (Page no. 426)

```
static int simple_remap_mmap(struct file *filp, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
if (remap_pfn_range(vma, vma->vm_start, vm->vm_pgoff,
                    vma->vm_end - vma->vm_start,
                    vma->vm_page_prot))
    return -EAGAIN;
...
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11496999/232955

Answer (score 5):

venk, I am just a newbie.
I am very curious about your question, and also I have read the part that you pointed in Linux device driver.

There is another book I should recommend, Professional Linux kernel architecture. 
some details on mmap are described there.

from within the book above, it seems there are some transformations to vm->vm_pgoff before calling the function simple_remap_mmap() as a example here, which does not exist in Linux kernel source code.

so, even if vm_pgoff is 0, after some transformation to it, there may be a correct value in that member variable vm_pgoff.

the codes below are present in Linux kernel source code 3.3.5

```
#ifdef CONFIG_DEVKMEM

static int mmap_kmem(struct file *file, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{

    unsigned long pfn;

    /* Turn a kernel-virtual address into a physical page frame */

    pfn = __pa((u64)vma->vm_pgoff << PAGE_SHIFT) >> PAGE_SHIFT;   <----- Here

    /*
     * RED-PEN: on some architectures there is more mapped memory than
     * available in mem_map which pfn_valid checks for. Perhaps should add a
     * new macro here.
     *
     * RED-PEN: vmalloc is not supported right now.
     */
    if (!pfn_valid(pfn))
        return -EIO;

    vma->vm_pgoff = pfn;
    return mmap_mem(file, vma);
}
#endif
```